# How to grab the same range on multiple columns.

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm working on a spreadsheet that does some pretty bizarre calculations... The long and the short of it is that I need to search the values in the 4 folowing ranges.

C5:C293, E5:E293, G5:G293 & I5:I293. The issue is that those ranges can change but will stay consistent across the columns. So For example instead of 5:293 it might change to 5:290. Is there an easy way to say "Look at the cells that are rows X:Y and are in columns A, B, C or D?"

Comment: for what??  What is the desired output when you find what you are looking for?  There are too many possible answers.  You need to be more specific with how you intend on using it.

Comment: @ScottCraner the 4 other people who provided helpful answers seem to disagree with your analysis.

Answer (score 3):

[google-spreadsheets](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets)

- ARRAYFORMULA: Commas `,` arrange the array horizontally and semi colons`;` arrange the array vertically( stacking on top of each other)

  `=ARRAYFORMULA ({C5:C293,E5:E293,G5:G293,I5:I293})`
- QUERY: If there's a pattern in the columns, This will isolate the array:

  `=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(C5:I293),"Select * skipping 2",0)`

Answer (score 2):

In Excel, use the INDIRECT() function.

So, have a Start cell in A1, and an End cell in A2.  Then your formulas to sum a range would reference the ranges for C column as:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("C"&A1&":C"&B1))
```

And D column as:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("D"&A1&":D"&B1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use range names rather than Indirect() or Offset() functions in the worksheet.

Create one range that covers the desired rows in the first column, e.g. "red" in the example, then create additional range names that offset the required columns from that range name.

[image]

How you construct your initial range is totally up to the circumstances, but the range names with Offset() will be super fast to deliver a result, whereas Indirect() and Offset() in worksheet cells can cause significant speed issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use `offset` function, if you are in [google-spreadsheets](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets), use it dinamically:

`=offset(C5,,,counta(C5:C),1)`

will reproduce the range of a proper length.